# How to write ኤ using Ubuntu's Amharic(sera (m17n) keyboard?

Tags: keyboard-layout

I could't figure out the key combinations to write ኤ on Ubuntu 20.04.4. I am using the layout 'Amharic(sera (m17n)' to type Amharic. I couldn't find anything on Google.

Answer (score 0):

If memory serves, ኤ is just <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, is it not? Alex Menk put out [a pretty handy PDF](http://s3lf.de/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/write_amharic_in_ubuntu-full.pdf) a decade or so back that shows how to type Amharic characters on Ubuntu.

Comment: You are right - It worked. Thank you! I am new to Ubuntu and wasn't able to find any documents. And the PDF, I think, is essential for all new Ethiopian users.

Comment: Share the PDF with anyone who uses Ubuntu. I was using this many years ago as part of some studies in scripture, and it was incredibly helpful 

Comment: This question might be very old. But I didn't know any better place to ask this. The PDF you pointed out was great and all but does not cover a few essential letters like 'ሏ', 'ሗ', 'ሟ', etc (I don't really know their categorical names). Writing Amharic is almost impossible without these letters. Are they really implemented in the layout and if not is there a way for me to contribute? I am a software engineer myself and I would be happy if I can help solve this issue.